Could not find Chrome (ver. 127.0.6533.72). puppeteer
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 127.0.6533.72). This can occur if either
you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: C:\Users\Kamaldeep\.cache\puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.

I installed the puppeteer using $env:PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD="true"  =>  npm i puppeteer [At that time if i did'nt skip $env:PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD="true" this download then i was getting this below error
[cause]: Error: The browser folder (C:\Users\\.cache\puppeteer\chrome\win64-127.0.6533.72) exists but the executable (C:\Users\\.cache\puppeteer\chrome\win64-127.0.6533.72\chrome-win64\chrome.exe) is missingnpm ERR!       at installUrl (file:///C:/Users//Desktop/current/biddingTool/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/install.js:114:23)


Tried $env:PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD="true"  =>  npm i puppeteer
Uninstalling/installing node-Modules
Updated the system chrome


Assuming you are running npm commands on the same host that is executing the Puppeteer script, running npx puppeteer browsers install chrome will resolve ensure you have the proper Chrome version for the version of Puppeteer.
